# Error when retrieving credentials from Environment: No credentials found in credential_source referenced in profile

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, boto3, aws-cli

`Env` file:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT=json
```

`Config` file:

```
[profile a]
credential_source = Environment
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn

[profile b]
credential_source = Environment
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn

[profile c]
credential_source = Environment
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn
```

`Dockerfile` content:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.2-python3.8
ARG AIRFLOW_USER_HOME=/opt/airflow
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/"
RUN pip install -r requirements.pip
ADD ./my_path/aws/config /home/airflow/.aws/config
```

Volume in compose:

```
- ./my_path/aws:/home/airflow/.aws
```

If I run:

```
docker exec -it my-container bash
aws configure list
```

I see:

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     *******************A              env    
secret_key     *******************x              env    
    region                eu-west-1              env    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

The error I get when running some `Python3` code using `boto3` is:

```
Error when retrieving credentials from Environment: No credentials found in credential_source referenced in profile.
```

Why is happening that if acces_key and secret are setup, and config file is indication that source is environment?

**Extra tests:**

I run: `aws s3 ls` inside the container and it list everything, so credentials are correctly setup from the env file.

Moreover the python code raising the issue is:

```
class Boto3AwsClient(object):
def __init__(self, localhost, profile):
    self.running_localhost = localhost
    self.profile = profile
    if self.running_localhost == 1:
        self.session = boto3.Session(profile_name=self.profile)
    else:
        self.session = boto3.Session()

def aws_client_connect(self, service=None):
    if service is None:
        raise ValueError('Service is not defined in new boto3 session.')

    service_client = self.session.client(service)
    return service_client
```

I tried also to settup the `config` file like this:

```
[default]
credential_source = Environment
region=eu-west-1
output=json

[profile a]
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn

[profile b]
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn

[profile c]
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn
```

And do not work neither.
The only feasible way is to have a config file and the credentials file, and do not setup the ENV variables. The problem with that is it's not a good practice.

Comment: `credential_source = Environment` is superfluous because env vars are checked first by default. How are you exporting the contents of the `Env` file to the environment?

Comment: @jordanm in the docker-compose I use: `env_file:
      - ./environtment_config/airflow_config/airflow.env`

Answer (score 0):

Assign the correct IAM role to the instance to access the s3